# Send data between Polymer Elements using iron-ajax

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, iron-form

I'm having the **my-app.html** which does have the app-toolbar, app-drawerlayout and etc which is loading the my menu elements(**myView1.html** and **myView2.html**).

I have **iron-ajax** call in myView1.html so when the response comes in the myView1.html it should **navigate** to myView2.html with **response** data came from the iron-ajax call

```
 // Function called when the response comes from iron-ajax
 function navigateToView2(data) {
        window.href = "/myView2";
 }
```

Please Help me, thanks in Advance

Comment: Please update the question to include the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a SPA (Single Page Application) and using the app-route element you will need to fire your own event from myView1.html to the my-app.html that contains the results of your ajax call. Then have the my-app.html change the app-route path to myView2.html. All while using data-binding to send the ajax response to the myView2.html. Events Up / Data Down! When using app-route the my-app.html file should control the changing of the SPA pages especially if you are needing to make sure to perform some kind of data-binding before loading the new page.